# Why the ith coefficient of $|\lambda I-A|$ is the sum of all $i$-th order principle minors of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, taylor-expansion, determinant

I come across a theorem that

$f(\lambda )=|\lambda I-A|$, which equals to $\lambda ^{n}-a_{1}\lambda
^{n-1}+\alpha _{2}\lambda ^{n-2}-...(-1)^{n}a_{n}$

where $a_{i}$ is the sums of all ith order principle minors.

I wonder why this is true?

What I tried to do is to use taylor expression to expand the determinant function as

$f(\lambda )=f(0)+\frac{f^{\prime }(0)}{1}\lambda + \frac{f^{(2)}(0)}{2}\lambda^{2}+... $

but it is hard to relate the higher order derivative of determinant with the
principle minors

I think this theorem should be frequently used, since it can relate the eigenvalue with matrix elements,  but it is weird that when I google with key words "principal minor determinant expansion " doesn't give me much clue. Maybe I am not using the proper key words.

Anyone can give me a hand please ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Isn't it just by the definition of determinant?

Comment: Consider the [Leibniz formula for the determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants).